# Borrow and internal IntoIterator

Tags: rust, lifetime

I though I got smart with lifetimes, but the compiler teaches me again...

> error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of method

[play](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021)

```rust
pub struct Bugger<S> {
    pub items: S,
}
impl<S> Bugger<S>
where
    &'static S: IntoIterator + 'static,
    <&'static S as IntoIterator>::Item: AsRef<u8>,
{
    fn do_something_with_items(&self) -> impl  Iterator<Item = u8> {
        (&self.items).into_iter().map(|b| *b.as_ref())
    }
}
```

I want to accept a generic member that implements the IntoIterator on it's reference and then use it in another method, actually a trait impl, but even this fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The primary reason this fails to compile is because you take `&self` (which must be valid for any lifetime) but the bound on the implementation block requires `IntoIterator` to be implemented for a reference with `'static` lifetime. The way you use this bound in the method therefore requires that the `&self` reference also be `'static`, but you've not indicated this.  You can fix this specific example by having the method take `&'static self`.

However, this is likely not what you want anyway.  Most likely, you want a lifetime shorter than `'static`.  You can describe this in the trait bound with a [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (HRTB).

You also need to indicate in the return type that the returned iterator borrows from `self`, which you can do by adding the anonymous lifetime `'_` to the bound.

```
pub struct Bugger<S> {
    pub items: S,
}

impl<S> Bugger<S>
where
    for<'a> &'a S: IntoIterator,
    for<'a> <&'a S as IntoIterator>::Item: AsRef<u8>,
{
    fn do_something_with_items(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> + '_ {
        (&self.items).into_iter().map(|b| *b.as_ref())
    }
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e38706bf3eb119204fc9773f97f304be))

Note that the anonymous lifetime is just syntactic sugar for this:

```
fn do_something_with_items<'a>(&'a self) -> impl Iterator<Item = u8> + 'a
```

Comment: The next level.. higher ranked. Thank you!